# How to use foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

How is a `foreach` loop used in C#?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
class ForEachTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] fibarray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
        foreach (int i in fibarray)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection. The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the desired information, but should not be used to change the contents of the collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.

Example:

```
class ForEachTest {                                                                      
    static void Main(string[] args)                                                      
    {                                                                                    
        int[] fibarray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };                             
        foreach (int i in fibarray)                                                      
        {                                                                                
            System.Console.WriteLine(i);                                                 
        }                                                                                
    } 
}
```

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the solution is very simple. Info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.80).aspx)

An example:

```
// Use a string array to loop over.
string[] ferns = { "Psilotopsida", "Equisetopsida", "Marattiopsida", "Polypodiopsida" };
// Loop with the foreach keyword.
foreach (string value in ferns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

More information and examples can be found here: http://dotnetperls.com/foreach