# C# for loop and encryption

Tags: c#, for-loop, encryption

I'm Kind of new to C# but since i have learned other programming languages before, learning it is going pretty well, However I am stuck on this one part, I am trying to "port" my old python application that takes a string or the users input and encrypts it. the python code is below, My problem is doing everything after and including the for loop. How might i go about searching for each letter in the Character string.

```
CHARACTER= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-=+_)(*&^%$#@!?><|:;}{]["

translated = ''


for uniqueKey in message:
    if uniqueKey in CHARACTER:
        num = CHARACTER.find(uniqueKey)

        if mode == "encrypt":
            num += key
        elif mode == "decrypt":
            num -= key
        if num >= len(CHARACTER):
            num -= len(CHARACTER)
        elif num < 0:
            num += len(CHARACTER)

        translated = translated + CHARACTER[num]
    else:
        translated = translated + uniqueKey
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code translation service.

Comment: @NathanBel Start by posting what you have tried in c# and where in your c# code are you stuck at rather than your python code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It'd be better if you were to include your attempt at a C# solution and what problems you are running into. "all of it" is going to get your question closed as too broad and/or missing required code.

Comment: As you ask only one question "How might i go about searching for each letter in the Character string." I will provide answer. Like that `string s = "kot";` `char c = s[1];`

Comment: Before posting, see all MSDN documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx  and SO references that may have solution to your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602871/how-to-use-foreach-loop-in-c-sharp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is `IndexOf()`.  This is the equivalent of your `find` call above:

```
foreach (var uniqueKey in message)
{
    var num = CHARACTER.IndexOf(uniqueKey);
    if (num  >= 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to comment downvoter?

Comment: Not the down voter but perhaps you would want to consider that spoonfed doesn't help the OP as he will not learn from it and will just come back to get more ready to go code. Specially when the question has been put on hold due to the lack of the user providing his trial and error.

Comment: Thank you.  I just thought I'd try to help somebody when nobody else was, and I needed the points.

Comment: Sometimes it hurts more than help, specially when you don't even know if the user attempted to do anything or just want people to convert the code for him to save the time.